# Can't create a working Android Virtual Device

Tags: java, android, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-tools

I can't seem to create an AVD that actually works correctly. They always end up looking like this, and none of the buttons really work. I'm just getting into Android programming so I'm not familiar with most of the settings. Can someone tell me a working configuration? The fields include:

-Name (not important, obviously)

-Device:

-Target:

-CPU/ABI:

-Skin:

-Memory Options--> RAM: and VM Heam:

-Internal Storage

-SD Card:

[Screenshot from current AVD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjAx5.jpg)

Comment: Try genymotion - it's the better way to run your apps ;)

Comment: except its not free....

Comment: it's free... just create an free account and sign in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of a setup I use for every day testing. If you're still having problems, there might be other issues with your setup.

`-Name Nexus` 5 API 23

`-Device:` Nexus 5 1080x1920 xxhdpi

`-Target:` Marshmallow Android 6.0 x86

`-CPU/ABI:` x86

`-Memory Options--> RAM: and VM Heam:` RAM=1536MB, VM=64MB

`-Internal Storage` 200MB

`-SD Card:` 100MB

I also want to +1 the GenyMotion comment above. It's free for individual use, so if you're just working on a personal project, download it for sure. It will change your life :)

Comment: This works for me with the one change of using ARM instead of x86. Not sure why, but at least it works. Thanks.

Comment: You'll generally want to use x86 on an intel machine as you'll get much better performance than ARM. In your SDK manager, in the "Extras" folder at the bottom, you can download the `Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)` to use Intel's proprietary emulating software. It will really speed things up when emulating using x86 devices.